# ID bug found in Mojave county, USA

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

What is this? I found it under a bed sheet. I live In Mojave county, AZ, USA, in the middle of the desert. It was probably 1/8 inch long. And narrow.

Answer (score 2):

Initial guess based on mouthparts, coloration and small size:

[Neuropteran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera) larva. Possibly a green lacewing (family [Chrysopidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopidae)).

See:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/204908)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Cedar Creek Ecosystem Science Reserve](https://www.cedarcreek.umn.edu/insects/album/023xxxapl.html)</sup>

According to [here](https://cals.arizona.edu/maricopa/garden/html/t-tips/bugs/lacewing.htm), green lacewings are found in Arizona deserts.

I will update in the morning with more detail...